# What is the difference between medical/biometric image and ordinary digital image from a CS point of view?

Tags: image, image-processing

When I read in the literature on image processing (e.g. image encryption) I find some papers that focus on the medical/biometric image. This is an example of these images: http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/english/Palmprint%20Databases.asp

The question:
from the computer science point of view: is there a difference between medical/biometric images and ordinary digital images, or they are just the same formats for different purposes?

Are not they just a bunch of pixels in JPEG format for example?

Comment: Not sure. I know there are two basic type of [image] compression, loss-less, and loss-ful.  "Biometric" must be the latter?  And/Or it could be some std./proprietary format specific to that industry.

Comment: Which literature are you referring to please? Can you provide a representative link?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Medical: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4530291. Biometric: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8081922

Comment: Different applications have different constraints, so you would compress images differently for different applications. Also, medical images are patient data, and have stringent laws governing their handling and storage. Likewise, biometric data is personally identifiable information, and has other laws controlling their use.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Are not they just a bunch of pixels in JPEG format for example?

Comment: @ThePrince, medical images are frequently in a file format called DICOM - but yes, they are still just fancy bitmaps. The difference is what they are images of. The problems found in médical certainly are present elsewhere, but think about the difference between an MRI taking a picture and trying to reason about it and CV in a more typical context of a factory production line.

Comment: In a commercially sold pharmacy packaging inspection system, for a right pill/wrong pill classifier - the acceptable false positive rate is 1:10,000,000. The accepted false negative rate is 5%.  That system does use standard PNG’s (albeit with RGB and Near IR), but the application requirements are very different from the average CV project.

Comment: “Are not they just a bunch of pixels in JPEG format for example?” Every image is just a bunch of pixels. Sometimes they’re stored as JPEG, sometimes as lossless TIFF, sometimes as an obscure proprietary format. But they’re all just a bunch of pixels, yes. And the same algorithms to process an MRI you could also use for a microscopy image or for a satellite image of the earth. But every application has different constraints, compare Mitch’s example of pill classification to classifying recycling materials. Both have very different costs associated to errors.